# How to give table an alternative name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to use a table that would be accessible under two names (something like e-mail address alias) i.e. I want queries:

`select * from my_table_name`

and

`select * from my_alt_table_name`

return records from the same table.

I know I can use a view and then run query on view, but wouldn't it be less efficient?

Comment: if you only want to use it for the `SELECT` queries, try to create `VIEW` and name it as an alias

Comment: *but wouldn't it be less efficient* less efficient how? What is it you think will be "less" efficient?

Comment: What's the point of having multiple names for the same table?

Comment: @Stu 'Less efficient' I mean that a view has first to select rows from a table and then run query on selected rows. See Akina'a answer for this question.

Comment: @Shadow I have quite big table that I store a copy of in some irregular time periods under name with suffix storing date (for example today copy would be: mytable_copy_20220117) and I want to use most recent table copy in queries and php scripts. So I figured that having alternative name like mytable_last_copy that I would give to latest copy is the way to achieve this with least changes it will require.

Comment: @MarekJ. well as Akina says with a simple *select * from table* there is no difference, and that's all you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can use a view and then run query on view, but wouldn't it be less efficient?

If the view is strictly `SELECT * FROM table`, without any additions (WHERE and so on), then there is no difference does you use the table or the view as an alias.

See [small DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c857405caa0aaff3f49f28111381a3d).

See `SHOW WARNING` outputs - they claims that the server is smart enough for to understand that it may/must use the table itself.

See `EXPLAIN` outputs - they claims that the server is smart enough for to understand that it may/must use the index which is present in the table structure.

---

[expanded DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddff7f3f01d2922cc8a8758ffa43c2a7) - analyse it by itself.

Also study [CREATE VIEW Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html), ALGORITHM  clause, and [View Processing Algorithms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html). Try to add `ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE` to DEMO and investigate the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a table with multiple names, so yeah, just use views. There will be no impact on performance during the runtime, however during the compilation of the query, there will be just a small delay time for the compilation of the view to be transformed into a table in memory which is absolutely negligible

```
CREATE VIEW table_name_alias AS SELECT * FROM table_name;

SELECT * FROM table_name_alias;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `view` would look like this

```
CREATE VIEW my_alt_table_name AS SELECT * FROM my_table_name;
```

and next time you can use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_alt_table_name ;
```